# How to get File List Array from Directory in android 10/11?

Tags: java, android

Does not get file list. it's get null Array.

```
fileArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    File[] files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/myfile").listFiles();
    if (files!=null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            fileArrayList.add(file);
        }
        fileListAdapter = new FileListAdapter(activity, fileArrayList, DownloadFragment.this::getPosition);
        binding.rvFileList.setAdapter(fileListAdapter);
    } else {
        binding.tvNoResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

in log display array null

```
2021-05-27 18:21:02.513 10083-10083/com.myapp.filez E/getAllFiles:: null
```

Comment: That is on an Android 10 device only  i think. Or else you should check first if subdir InstaDownloader existst. Do it step by step instead of in one code line.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurs in only android 10 or 11 version?
It's Solution is Below:

Include line in Manifest:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: No. For an Android 10 device that indeed does the trick. But that request does nothing for an Android 11 device.  And.. on an Android 11 device you will not have that null listing to begin with.